# How to fix Call to a member function where() on int

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have to update some records but it doesn't work properly.
Someone know what to do?

```
$dog = DB::table('dogs')
    ->update($data)
    ->where('id', $id);
```

return response()->json($dog);
})

Comment: First of all, please post code relevant to your problem in text form, properly formatted - do not show images of code.

Comment: Second, go check the documentation, for what the `update` method is supposed to return.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updates suggests that you need to call these methods in opposite order.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your feedback, is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `where` before `update`, e.g. :

```
$dog = DB::table('dogs')->where('id', $id)->update($data);
```